# How can I launch git-for-windows SDK's git-bash in Windows Terminal?

Tags: git-for-windows

There's git for Windows, and then there's git for Windows SDK. Both provide a git-bash.exe shell, but when executing the one from the SDK it always opens in its own window. I'd like to be able to use it as a tab in Windows Terminal. Is there a setting I can change to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to find instructions for this on the MSYS2 site (since git for windows SDK essentially wraps MSYS2): https://www.msys2.org/docs/terminals/

Basically the command is
`C:\path\to\gitsdk\msys2_shell.cmd -defterm -here -no-start -mingw64`

Comment: Thank you, this command is exactly what I needed to integrate git for windows sdk's terminal in intellij

Answer (score -3):

• for x86

```
start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

• for x64

```
start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Other Windows Terminal profiles don't use the `start` command and the SDK has no bin folder.