# Terminal resize issue with Intellij and Git for Windows SDK

Tags: mingw-w64, msys2, mingw32, git-for-windows

I am on Windows running Intellij and Git for Windows SDK for a feature rich terminal on Windows (pacman, oh my zsh, etc...)

I looked up previously on which command to use to make it the default Intellij Terminal and SO delivered:

[How can I launch git-for-windows SDK's git-bash in Windows Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734721/how-can-i-launch-git-for-windows-sdks-git-bash-in-windows-terminal)

I am using the cmd from above's 2nd post:

```
C:\git-sdk-64\msys2_shell.cmd -defterm -here -no-start -mingw64
```

Everything works fine except for a stubborn resizing issue :

Every time I resize the Intellij Terminal, the MSYS terminal stops receiving key strokes and I have to reopen a new one:

[image: (can't type after the resize under the echo hello )]

( can't type after the resize under the echo hello )

Trying to avoid WSL for now as I noticed maven builds through wsl were noticeably slower than directly on powershell or via git terminal.

**Workaround**

Not exactly a solution but if you run with MinGW32, the resize no longer causes the problem

To be seen if I will suffer from other 32/64 bit incompatibilities

using for now:

```
C:\git-sdk-64\msys2_shell.cmd -defterm -here -no-start -mingw32
```

Comment: Isn't it reproducible in terminal outside IDE? Looks like here was similar case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-297156/Terminal-becomes-unresponsive-when-using-git-from-CLI-and-resizing-terminal-view

Comment: I pasted the same command to the MS Terminal app that comes with Win 11 and you are right!

it's reproducible outside the IDE, hoping I am just missing a flag on that launch command